# Getting java.util.NoSuchElementException while trying to handle multiple browser windows using selenium webdriver with java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, collections

I am trying to handle multiple browser windows using selenium webdriver, but getting java.util.NoSuchElementException. A week ago this code was working fine but now getting issue in the code while trying to switch to third window.

The issue I am getting on line `String Third_window = iterate.next();`

Note: This code was working fine properly a week ago.

```
  public class Firefox {
        public static WebDriver driver;

        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
                    "C:\\Users\\singhais\\Documents\\Selenium Prerequisites\\geckodriver.exe");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("https://www.hdfcbank.com/");
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            // First window
            System.out.println("GettingID for first Window");
            Set<String> win = driver.getWindowHandles();
            Iterator<String> iterate = win.iterator();

            String first_window = iterate.next();
            System.out.println(first_window);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='element2']/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/a/img")).click();

            // second window
            System.out.println("GettingID for second Window");
            win = driver.getWindowHandles();
            iterate = win.iterator();

            first_window = iterate.next();
            System.out.println(first_window);
            System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
            String second_window = iterate.next();
            System.out.println(second_window);
            driver.switchTo().window(second_window);
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='wrapp']/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a")).click();

            // ThirWindow
            System.out.println("GettingID for third Window");
            win = driver.getWindowHandles();
            iterate = win.iterator();
            first_window = iterate.next();
            System.out.println(first_window);
            second_window = iterate.next();
            System.out.println(second_window);
            String Third_window = iterate.next();
            System.out.println(Third_window);
            driver.switchTo().window(Third_window);
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

            Thread.sleep(3000);
            driver.close();

            driver.switchTo().window(second_window);

            Thread.sleep(3000);
            driver.close();

            driver.switchTo().window(first_window);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a")).click();

            Thread.sleep(6000);
            driver.close();

        }

    }
```

This code is not duplicate of the problem mentioned in given link below. In my issue I am getting NoSuchElementException while trying to navigate to last window.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switching into new window using selenium after button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47082900/switching-into-new-window-using-selenium-after-button-click)

Comment: @DebanjanB No, this issue is not duplicate. In my case I am getting NoSuchElement exception while trying to switch to last window.

Comment: can you please post your full error console log

Comment: @zsbappa, Here is the full console log `Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextNode(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
 at hdfcbank.Firefox.main(Firefox.java:56)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Thread.sleep(3000);` Your program works fine for me.I just wait 3s for getting next windows

```
        System.out.println("GettingID for third Window");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        win = driver.getWindowHandles();
        iterate = win.iterator();
```

Please check and let me know

Comment: Thanks @zsbappa for your opinion on this, but I have latest gecko driver.

Firefox.java is my class name, i think you got confused with this.

Comment: Many Thanks, it is working fine. How did you come to this solution, I mean what you have thought. I have not thought about the wait because previously it was working fine.

Comment: It happens when everything perfectly works but elements not visible..Thanks if you need anything more feel free knock me anytime