# Open tab, close tab, and quit Firefox on Mac using Selenium?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

I've been searching around for answers, but I cannot get my code to work. What I would like to happen is that I can open a tab, open a new webpage, and then close that same tab. From there, once i'm done doing my work, I'd like it to quit the program. As of now, it will not open a new tab, close the new tab, and quit the application. What is doing right now, is that it opens up google, then loads stackoverflow in the same tab.

Right now, I have...

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')
time.sleep(5)
driver.get("https://www.stackoverflow.com")
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 'w')
time.sleep(5)
driver.Dispose()
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switching into new window using selenium after button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47082900/switching-into-new-window-using-selenium-after-button-click)

Comment: Using iterator - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46251494/best-way-to-keep-track-of-windows-with-selenium-in-ie11/46346324#46346324

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code to get desired result:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
# Get current window/tab ID
current_window = driver.current_window_handle
# Open StackOverflow in new window/tab
driver.execute_script("window.open('https://www.stackoverflow.com')")
# Get new window/tab ID
new_window = [window for window in driver.window_handles if window != current_window][0]
# Switch to new window/tab
driver.switch_to.window(new_window)
# Close new window/tab
driver.close()
# Switch to initial window/tab
driver.switch_to.window(current_window)
# Quit Webdriver
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks for this! it worked. I just have a question about this implementation.

1. Is there a benefit or reason why you used driver.execute_script vs driver.get?
2. for the line: new_window = [window for window in driver.window_handles if window != current_window][0]  
Why does this work? Is this just acting as a place holder?

Comment: 1. `driver.execute_script("window.open(URL)` allows to open URL in new tab while `driver.get(URL)` - in the same tab. 2. I'm not sure I understand what do you mean by *placeholder* in this case... This line allows you to get window from the list of currently available windows which is different from initial window...

Comment: Much appreciated for the clarification. For #2, I just meant, placeholder, as the window it self. So currentwindow would be a place holder for tab 0(google), then new_window would be a placeholder for tab 1(stackoverflow)

Comment: It's an ID for window. Looks like `'CDwindow-24a4cac9-a500-4cfa-b0b1-fe5490612705'`

Comment: You can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solved your problem