# How to iterate through web pages in chrome using WebDriver Selenium in python?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a written a program that will open windows in chrome, iterate through them to find a specific one and close that window if found.

I used a Mac OS python import and am having trouble converting this line:

`for item in app('Web Chrome').window[0].tabs():`

into a windows friendly version using webdriver. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switching into new window using Selenium after button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47082900/switching-into-new-window-using-selenium-after-button-click)

Comment: [Switching into new window using Selenium after button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47082900/switching-into-new-window-using-selenium-after-button-click) doesn't solve this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try with `window_handle` function?

```
for handle in driver.window_handles:
    driver.switch_to_window(handle)
```